# How to create a name for a var in output of groupby - Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have some data in excel that I imported into a dataframe in Python (Base_Eventos). I need to summarize a variable (PartyID), so I use:

`Base_Eventos.groupby (by = 'partyID'). Size ()`

Since the result comes out with a part of the counter without a variable name. And I will need to use this count output to make a filter. How can I transform this output with a name for a newly created variable? base ex:

idPartida   **count** (I want to add this variable name because it comes null)

x123           **67**

x124           **86**

x135           **54**

Comment: Hi Lorena. Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please translate your question into English? Thank you!

Comment: @Vishal please don't translate for other users. They must do it themselves.

Comment: In português https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Base_Eventos.groupby(by='idPartida').count()` instead.